# PHP preg_match_all regular expression to get pixel values (with "px") from css

Tags: php, css, regex, preg-match-all, pixel

I'm looking for a regular expression for use with PHP's `preg_match_all()` function, which will give me all of the `px` values from a CSS file.

For example, if the css below is used, then the expected result would be an array of:

```
array ( "11px", "0.45px", "11.0005px", "1.1px", "888.888px" )
```

The `$pattern` string is what I have so far -- it doesn't appear to work, however.

The logic I was trying to use is: the number before the decimal can be up to 4 digits, the decimal symbol is optional, and the number after the decimal is optional, up to 4 digits, followed by "px".

```
$pattern = "/([0-9]{1,4}\.*[0-9]{1,4}*px)/";

$css = '
.some_class {
    font-size: 11px;
    margin-left: 0.45px;
    margin-top:11.0005px;
    border: 1.1px solid blue;
}
.another_class {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    width: 100%;
    color: #012345;
    z-index: 12;
    font-size: calc(100% + 888.888px);
}
';
preg_match_all($pattern, $css, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- a capture group is unnecessary and will only slow down the regex engine.
- `\b` will ensure that only full qualifying numbers are matched
- `\d` is a shorter syntax for `[0-9]`.
- to match zero or one of something use `?`.  `*` means zero or more.
- since not all pixel values are floats (`11px`), you can make the decimal place digits and trailing one to four digits optional by wrapping in a non-capturing group and adding a zero or one quantifier (`?`).
- your pattern was breaking because you used two consecutive quantifiers: `{1,4}*` which is like saying "match 1 to 4 0 or more occurrences".  The regex engine was like: "huh?"

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/oufTK)) ([Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fb8TYZ/2))

```
$css = '
.some_class {
    font-size: 11px;
    margin-left: 0.45px;
    margin-top:11.0005px;
    border: 1.1px solid blue;
}
.another_class {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    width: 100%;
    color: #012345;
    z-index: 12;
    font-size: calc(100% + 888.888px);
}';
$pattern = "/\b\d{1,4}(?:\.\d{1,4})?px/";

var_export(preg_match_all($pattern, $css, $matches) ? $matches[0] : 'fail');
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '11px',
  1 => '0.45px',
  2 => '11.0005px',
  3 => '1.1px',
  4 => '888.888px',
)
```

Patterns with greater validation:

- Checks that the 1-4 digit number is preceded by a colon or a space (`\K` restarts the fullstring match):

  ```
  /[: ]\K\d{1,4}(?:\.\d{1,4})?px/
  ```
- Checks that the 1-4 digit number is not preceded by a digit:

  ```
  /\D\K\d{1,4}(?:\.\d{1,4})?px/
  ```

Your sample input uses zeros before decimal points.  If the zeros are optional, my pattern will need adjusting.  These will allow floats without a leading digit while requiring that dot is trailed by a digit.

1. `/\D\K(?:\d{1,4}|\d{0,4}\.\d{1,4})px/`
2. `/\D\K\d{0,4}(?:\.(?=\d))?\d{1,4}px/`

Comment: hi, I think that your answer is fantastic! Just one question: you noted that if zeros are optional, then the pattern will need adjusting. It turns out that there are some styles like: font-size: .5px Can you clarify how this might be adjusted to take this into account? Thanks!!

Comment: Just a sec. I'll adjust.

Comment: I'm guessing that the first "{1,4}" would be changed to "{0,4}", true?

Comment: that will work, but then it will also match `px` (with no leading digits) This is a fringe case though.  Perhaps there is no consequence for your project.

Comment: This one seems to work the best for me: /\d{0,4}\.?\d{0,6}px/

Comment: I could also imagine space between digit and `px` but that isn't mentioned by OP. Very well explained and extensive answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just made correction from your pattern,

```
$pattern = "~([0-9]{1,4})px|([0-9]{1,4}?\.[0-9]{1,4})px~";

$css = '
.some_class {
    font-size: 11px;
    margin-left: 0.45px;
    margin-top:11.0005px;
    border: 1.1px solid blue;
}
.another_class {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    width: 100%;
    color: #012345;
    z-index: 12;
    font-size: calc(100% + 888.888px);
}
';
preg_match_all($pattern, $css, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

**Data in `$matches`:**

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '11px',
    1 => '0.45px',
    2 => '11.0005px',
    3 => '1.1px',
    4 => '888.888px',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => '11',
    1 => '',
    2 => '',
    3 => '',
    4 => '',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => '',
    1 => '0.45',
    2 => '11.0005',
    3 => '1.1',
    4 => '888.888',
  ),
```

)

Comment: @mickmackusa how / what did you find incorrect/inaccurate ?

Comment: @mickmackusa I agree with with you and updated the answer.

Comment: You are using too many capture groups which generate unnecessary output array bloat and cost more steps.  Your pattern will match the last four digits of a 5-or-more-digit number.  The lazy `?` after `{1,4}` doesn't make a difference.  Pipes cost steps and your pattern isn't very DRY.  (leaving my computer now)

Comment: I can't see what could be more correct in this answer, further it lacks any explanation.